# How do you describe the motion of a horse when it brakes?

Tags: verbs, adjectives

I always see horses in the movies raise their front legs in the air when they are halted by the riders. How would you describe the motion when they do such thing?

[[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airs_above_the_ground):[image]

Comment: Do you mean riders, rather than grooms?

Comment: @DrXorile Yes. And thank you for the correction! :)

Comment: Typically rearing or rearing up. https://www.google.com/search?q=horse+rearing+up&safe=active&client=ms-android-google&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6j5yltvPTAhUL7WMKHWL1Dm4Q_AUICSgB&biw=412&bih=604

Comment: @DrXorile Ah, that's what I'm looking for. Appreciate it!

Comment: @Xanne - http://m.wikihow.com/Teach-a-Horse-to-Rear

Comment: Yes, I realize now you can teach it, or the horse can do it out of fear or whatever without being commanded to do so.  Same word, rear.

Comment: Also [rampant](https://www.google.com/search?q=horse+rampant&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6k--1wvPTAhVFOyYKHX9SBZ4Q_AUICigB&biw=1024&bih=585), but half the hits include 1 rear leg in the air, and fore legs extended.

Comment: @DrXorile now I've answered I see you got there first. I don't want to steal your rep points if you want to answer, or I can make mine CW so I don't gain from it.

Comment: @chrish, no problem. Enjoy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the horse is doing is [*rearing (up)*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearing_(horse)) (Wikipedia link for more than a definition). Oxford has [*verb (2)* (of a horse or other animal) raise itself upright on its hind legs](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rear). It may be as part of a panic stop, or it might be the result of training for display as in the picture you show. In the latter case it requires skill and training from both the horse and rider; in the former it's dangerous at least for inexperienced riders, and is not normal stopping behaviour. It would be quite intimidating if you were standing near it, and would also be a way of showing off the rider's skill. It's probably just a movie stunt thing rather than historically accurate (assuming you're referring to westerns)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'll hopefully edit in a definition from a dictionary when I've got a better connection. I'll ask Dr Xorile if they mind - there's always CW, and I missed the comment.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is "putting the brakes on"[sic]. The riding apparel and position of the horse both suggest that this is a dressage exercise from the Spanish Riding School in Vienna.

May I refer the OP to the Google images of the *Spanish riding school Vienna*.

However, the chestnut horse is not that of the famous white *Lipazzaner* breed of horse associated with the school.

The movement that the painting depicts may well be from  "classical dressage, the Levade and the Presade, in which the rider asks [sic] the horse to set [sic] well back on its hindquarters and raise its front legs off the ground to vairying [sic] degrees". (Wikipedia)

Comment: Could you say what the horse is exactly doing more succinctly? You could also add a link to the wikipedia article, which seems to be about the painting itself. And I think the word *vairying* needs another [*sic*] too.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  I shall edit my answer along the lines suggested in your comment. I don't think the Wikipedia entry I read is about the painting in the OP.  I shall also have to figure out how to link my answer directly to the sources cited. My computer skills are as well developed as my ability to brake and steer a horse.

Comment: Copy and paste the url address? Or even better, look at the editor tool box, see the chain link icon? Highlight the word(s) in the text you wish to embed the link, click the icon above, paste the url address in the space that appears, and voilà , *è fatto*!